# Trying to uv ids from vertex in maya using python

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to create a tool in maya that checks if the uv shells are overlapping and it's turning out to be a bit of a challege. So far Ive managed to get the vertex ID's of a mesh but I've struggled to get the corresponding uv ids. At the moment I have this code but the u and v variables print as none and I cant understand why that is?
Any ideas on how I can get the uv ids of a mesh?

This is the code I have:

```
    def check_overlapping_uvs(self, dag_path, grid_resolution=10):
    # Find UV set name
    uv_set_name = cmds.polyUVSet(dag_path.fullPathName(), currentUVSet=True, query=True)
    print(uv_set_name)
    # Convert UV set name to UV selection
    num_vertices = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(dag_path.fullPathName(), fromUV=True, toVertex=True)
    print(num_vertices)
    vertices = cmds.ls(num_vertices, flatten=True)
    print(vertices)

    # Get the UVs of the mesh
    u_array = []
    v_array = []
    for vertex in vertices:
        # Retrieve the UV values for each vertex
        u = cmds.polyEditUV(vertex, uValue=True, uvs=uv_set_name)
        v = cmds.polyEditUV(vertex, vValue=True, uvs=uv_set_name)
        print(u, v)
        # u_array.append(u[0])
        # v_array.append(v[1])
```

To note the selected mesh is coming from a seperate function which the code is here for reference:

```
        for geo in selected_geo:
        print(selected_geo)
        if self.stop_validation_flag:
            break

        shape_nodes = cmds.listRelatives(geo, shapes=True)
        if shape_nodes:
            shape_node = shape_nodes[0]
            selection_list = om.MSelectionList()
            selection_list.add(shape_node)
            dag_path = om.MDagPath()
            selection_list.getDagPath(0, dag_path)

            uv_check = self.check_overlapping_uvs(dag_path)
```